# Problem with serial port in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, snap

I have a Java program that list the Serial-port in my Ubuntu 16.4 LTS system, its working fine, listing all the serial ports in my system . Then I created the snap of the same project as per the snapcraft instruction, after install the snap in my Ubuntu 16.4 LTS system , its not list the serial ports, throwing the below error.

I got this error:

```
check_group_uucp(): error testing lock file creation Error details:Permission deniedcheck_lock_status: No permission to create lock file.
```

please see: How can I use Lock Files with `rxtx`? in INSTALL…

Note : We are using `RXTXcomm.jar` and `librxtxSerial.so` to run the Java application.

Someone please help me to solve this?